# How to disable rich calendar using JQuery or javascript (client side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, richfaces

All is in the question, I want to disable and enable a `rich:calendar` on the client side (using a javascript fonction for example).

xhtml elements:

```
<rich:calendar id="calendar" ... />          
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox" onclick="change('checkbox', 'calendar')" ... />
```

JS Function :

```
function change(checkbox, calendar){
    if(jQuery('#'+checkbox).is(':checked')){
        // Enable calendar
        jQuery('#'+calendar).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else{
        // Disable calendar
        jQuery('#'+calendar).attr('disabled',true);
    }
}
```

`jQuery('#'+checkbox)` returns an input `input#checkbox`
but `jQuery('#'+calendar)` returns a table `table#calendar.rich-calendar-exterior` and not the components to disabled.

How to disable the input and the icon of the rich calendar using JQuery (or javascript) ?

**Edit** : 
`<rich:calendar id="calendar" />` generates html :

```
<span id="calendarPopup"> 
  <input type="text" class="rich-calendar-input" id="calendar" name="calendar"
    style="vertical-align: middle; width: 130px">
  <img alt="" class="rich-calendar-button" id="calendarPopupButton"
    style="vertical-align: middle" src="/project/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.richfaces.renderkit.html.iconimages.CalendarIcon/DATB/eAE7fv4Kw6znAA4mA-w_.jsf">
  <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="calendarInputCurrentDate" name="calendarInputCurrentDate" style="display: none" value="11/2011">
</span>
```

Comment: If you can post the HTML passed to the browser (through view source) then people not familiar with richfaces can help you as well.

Comment: @JamesMontagne You can see my edit and my answer. My answer isn't exactly the expected implementation, so I'm still looking for a good answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a solution using only jQuery implmentation, so I choose to bind the checkbox value and the disabled calendar attribute on the same boolean :

```
<rich:calendar id="calendar" disabled="#{!checkboxValue}" />          
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox" value="#{checkboxValue}">
   <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="calendar"></a4j:support>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

There is ajax (I do not want to) does anyone have another solution without ajax ? Without other solution, I'll choose this one as the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is very old, but nonetheless I will contribute to it, because I just had the same doubt.

I was able to do it with `JQuery`. Looking at the generated `HTML` output I could see that it creates several components. Here's my `<rich:calendar>`

```
<rich:calendar id="cal" value="#{myManagedBean.date}" >
```

As you can see the id is `cal`. But it's internal `<input>`'s id is actually `calInputDate`, so that's the one that I disabled via `JQuery`, like this:

```
$('#mainForm\\:calInputDate').prop('disabled', true);
```

And just use the same logic to enable it again.

```
$('#mainForm\\:calInputDate').prop('disabled', false);
```

It works :-)

Comment: This does not disable the calendar button, but only the input-field