# Selenium cannot determine if richfaces calendar is disabled

Tags: selenium-webdriver, richfaces

I have a rich calendar:

```
<rich:calendar id="calendarId" disabled="true"..... />
```

And I try to determine with selenium if the calendar element is disabled

```
webDriver.findElement(By.id("calendarId")).isEnabled();
```

The result is *true*, despite of my calendar being disabled.

It is a known issue with this rich:calendar and selenium? Does anyone know how can I determine if the calendar is disabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable rich calendar using JQuery or javascript (client side)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012972/how-to-disable-rich-calendar-using-jquery-or-javascript-client-side)

Comment: I am not interested on how to disable/enable a rich:calendar on the client side. I just want to determine how can I check if a rich:calendar is disabled using selenium. As you can see, selenium returns bad results...

Comment: you probably should search for `"calendartId" + "InputDate"` (input id not component id)

Comment: @Emil Sierżęga, it works like you said. You can answer the question so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you. I just posted an answear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.id("calendarIdInputDate")).isEnabled();
```

It should be `clientID` of component + `"InputDate"` (which is a suffix added to input in calendar in RichFaces). It's because HTML element with `id="calendarId"` is just DIV wrapper for the rest of the component and it has no `disabled` attribute.